# Sizeof with array and pointer

Tags: c, sizeof

Could you please explain why code below produces different result. Using netbeans.

```
    #define SIZE 1

    size_t getSize( float *ptr );

    int main( void ) {

        float array[ SIZE ];
        //not getting the same results??? from sizeof/getSize

        printf( "The number of bytes in the array is %u\n"
                "The number of bytes returned by getSize is %u\n", 
                    sizeof( array ), getSize( array ) );
    }
    //sizeof( array ) prints 4
    //getSize( array ) prints 8

    size_t getSize( float *ptr ) {
        return sizeof( ptr );
    }
```

Comment: the size of a pointer is either 4 (32 bit system) or 8 (64 bit system).  The pointer has no idea as to the length of the area that it points to.

Comment: You should either cast `sizeof(xxx)` and `getSize(x)` as `(int)` or use `%zu` format in printf

Comment: Run, do not walk, to section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 2):

In main(), you are looking at the size of "int".
In getSize(), you are looking at the size of "pointer to float".

Depending on what you want to actually do, you might want to play around with the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 17

main()
{
  int       arrayINT[N];
  float     arrayFLOAT[N];

  printf("sizeof int is %d, sizeof of %d elements long array of int is %d, calculated number of elements in this array of int is %d\n",
     sizeof(int),
     N,
     sizeof(arrayINT),
     sizeof(arrayINT)/sizeof(int));
  printf("sizeof float is %d, sizeof of %d elements long array of float is %d, calculated number of elements in this array of float is %d\n",
     sizeof(float),
     N,
     sizeof(arrayFLOAT),
     sizeof(arrayFLOAT)/sizeof(float));
  printf("sizeof pointer to float is %d\n", sizeof(float*));

  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You should either cast `sizeof(xxx)` as `(int)` or use `%zu` format in `printf`

Comment: @chqrlie If, and only if, you're using a C99 compiler...

Comment: casting as `(int)` works fine for all versions as long as the objects are not too large.

Answer (score 0):

Because an array is not a pointer.

Just because an unsubscripted array evaluates to the address of its first element, that does not make it a pointer.

Comment: actually, obtaining the address of the first byte of an array IS obtaining a pointer to the array.

Comment: @user3629249 a pointer to an array is not the same beast  as a pointer to the first element of that array.

Comment: @user3629249 You can assign an address to a pointer, and make it **point** to something.  The array **has** an address - it **is** something.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` does not return the size of memory, but size of datatype. It is evaluated at compile time.

```
/* this is size of pointer - pointer is 4 byte on 32bit machine and 8 bytes on 64bit machine */
sizeof(float *);

/* this is size of a float, which is 4 bytes */
sizeof(float);

/* this is size of array of floats so it will be N*sizeof(float) */
sizeof(float[N]);
```

Inside your function `getSize`, you are evaluating datatype `float *`. In `main`, you are evaluating datatype `float[SIZE]` so `float[1]`.